# Automate requests to API for CRUD components in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios

The title may be a bit confusing. I'll try to explain this with examples. This is my basic react component to show a list of posts downloaded from an API.

```
// Rendered by react-router with path='/posts'
const Posts = props => {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])

  const requestHandler = async () => {
    const res = await MyApiClass.get("/posts")
    if (res.code === 200) setPosts(res.data)
    else console.log('Error')
  }

  useEffect(() => requestHandler(), [])

  const mapping = posts.map(post => <p key={post.id}>{post.title}</p>)

  return <div>{mapping}</div>
}
```

I reuse fragments like requestHandler, assigning response to state and running the requestHandler after the component is mounted. They would be almost identical for other assets like users or comments. And the same goes for show action for those assets.

Now let's assume that my routes in react-router are exactly the same as in my Api. Is it possible to automate this data download and put it state or props? Is it common? Are there any libraries for that? Would it cause problems? What are your opinions?

I was playing around for a bit with `react-router`, but did't come up with anything worth showing. The end result that I had in mind was something like that:

```
// Rendered by react-router with path='/users'
const Users = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.res.onSuccess = () => console.log('Data received')
    props.res.onError = () => console.log(props.res.code)
  }, [])
  const mapping = props.res.data.map(user => <p key={user.id}>{user.email}</p>)

  return <div>{mapping}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a data fetching hook and use it in the routes.

**useDataFetching.jsx**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import MyApiClass from "./MyApiClass"

function useDataFetching(dataSource) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const res = await MyApiClass.get(dataSource);
        if (res.code === 200) {
            setLoading(false)
            setResults(res.data);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error.message);
      }

      setLoading(false);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [dataSource]);

  return {
    error,
    loading,
    results
  };
}

export default useDataFetching;
```

Then in your route component, import the hook and use it like this:

```
 const { loading, results, error } = useDataFetching("/posts")
```